# Can paths crossover in Lode Runner?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

In the game [Lode Runner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lode_Runner), a *tile* is an element of the set $\{A,B,S,L,P\}$ (standing for air, brick, stone, ladder, pipe respectively), and a *stage* is a finite rectangular grid of tiles. We call $B,S$ *solid tiles*. The player occupies a single tile. Say the player is *supported* if the tile it occupies is $L$ or $P$, or the tile below it is $B,S$ or $L$. The player may move to an adjacent tile subject to the following rules:

1. The player may not move to a solid tile.
2. Subject to 1, the player may move down.
3. Subject to 1, a supported player may move left or right.
4. Subject to 1, a player occupying a ladder may move up.

Additionally, if a player is supported, the tile to its left is not solid, and the tile below that one is $B$, the player may *destroy* the $B$, temporarily converting it to $A$ for a fixed amount of time; after which it *solidifies* back to $B$. An example is shown below (the `*` represents the player):

```
A*    A*    A*
BS => AS => BS
```

Similarly the player may destroy a $B$ below and to the right.

For the purpose of this question, suppose the player moves arbitrarily fast. Equivalently, rather than solidifying after a delay, suppose the player may choose at any time to wait for the oldest destroyed $B$ to solidify (however note that the order of destruction must still equal the order of solidification). (The original game also includes enemies and gold; suppose these don't exist).

> Does there exist a stage in which the player can get from the top right to the bottom left, and from top left to bottom right, but not from top right to bottom right, nor from top left to bottom left?

Note that it is possible to satisfy the first three of the four conditions:

```
AAAAAA
SBAAAS
SSBBBS
AABBBS
ASBBBA
```

Comment: I'm sure custom maps (such as in the 1994 Sierra version) can produce a counterexample.

Comment: So on a ladder, a player can move up and left/right? but not down?

Comment: Observation: you certainly need bricks. Otherwise, in a level where you can get from TL to BR and TR to BL, there's at least one space where the two solution paths cross. At that space, you can't tell whether the player came from TL or TR (since player can't affect level) therefore from that space you can reach both BL and BR.  Not convinced it's possible even with bricks, but maybe.

Comment: @user326210 sorry, I missed that option. Will edit, thanks for catching.

Comment: If the player occupies a P space above an A space, can the player move into the A space? What if the player occupies a P space above a P space? I wasn't sure.

Comment: @user326210 yes to both. In fact the player can always move to the tile below if it is not solid. I tried to say this in rule 2; feel free to suggest a clearer wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the following solution using only $\{A,L,B\}$. I've replaced $A$ by spaces and added row/column labels, so eg `1b` refers to the top right tile. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpUsW.jpg) (of a slight variant) might be easier to visualize.

It works with the infinite player speed assumption given in the question, though in the real game block `55` solidifies too quickly. I would still be interested to see a simpler solution.

```
  123456789ab
1     BBB    
2 BBBBLLLBBBB
3   LL   LL  
4    L   L   
5 BB  B B  BB
6 BBBBBBBBBBB
7 BBBBBBBBBBB
8 BBBBBBBBBBB
9 BBBBBBBBBBB
a  BBBBBBBBB 
b  BBBBBBBBB
```

To get from `11` to `bb`, destroy `24,55,57,5a` in that order, then all tiles in the triangle with vertices `66,6a,aa`:

```
  123456789ab
1     BBB    
2 BBB LLLBBBB
3   LL   LL  
4    L   L   
5 BB        B
6 BBBBB     B
7 BBBBBB    B
8 BBBBBBB   B
9 BBBBBBBB  B
a  BBBBBBBB  
b  BBBBBBBBB
```

On the other hand, suppose we can get from `1b` to `bb`. Note that `5a,5b` can't be in the destroyed state at the same time, so we can't destroy `6b` or anything below it. Therefore we must destroy `aa`. Working backwards, it is easy to see that we must destroy the triangle with vertices `66,6a,aa`, and therefore must destroy `55,5a`. Now these can only be destroyed from positions `44,4b` respectively, so we must visit both. We can't get from `4b` to `44`, regardless of which bricks are destroyed. So we must get from `44` to `4b`, which is only possible if block `24` is destroyed. This can only be done from `13`, which can't be reached from `1b`, a contradiction.

The other two conditions follow by symmetry.

It's possible to construct an example using only $B$ and $L$, and both of those tiles are also necessary.